# How to add placeholder in date picker field using CSS

Tags: css, date, calendar, placeholder

Below is my CSS code:

```
div.hs-dateinput .hs-input{
    background: url(../../static/icons/calendar-grey.svg) no-repeat;
    background-size: 2rem 2rem;
    min-height: 44px;      
  }
```

Currently all other placeholder are coming from Hubspot but for date picker field hubspot does not provide any option to add placeholder so I need to add using CSS.

How can I add placeholder, as above is existing CSS.

I have also attached screenshot of my field which is without placeholder.

[image]

Comment: are you looking for css only solution? how your html looks like? provide more details so we can help

Comment: placeholder is an HTML attribute, not a CSS property.